# Model not getting updated in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-rest-framework

```
active = request.POST['isactive']
if active == 'True':
     user_profile.user.is_active = False
elif active == 'False':
     user_profile.user.is_active = True 
user_profile.user.save()
```

Hi, I am trying to update user status over a toggle button; user status gets updated in the database but does not reflect on User Interface.Have also tried transaction commit but no luck. Please help with a solution to solve this issue
Thank you!

**Edit :**
Adding form code

```
{% if isactive == True %}
    <button type="submit" form="form1" class="block">Block</button>
{% elif isactive == False %}
    <button type="submit" form="form1" class="unblock">Unblock</button>
{% endif %}
<form method="POST" id="form1" action="" >
   {% csrf_token %}
   <input type="hidden" id="isactive" name="isactive" value="{{ isactive }}">
</form>
```

Comment: What is the `isactive` widget? A checkbox? Please post the `<form>` code.

Comment: You're mixing boolean values as value (True / False) and as string ('True', 'False'). Try this: `if active == True:` and this: `elif active == False:`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Please find the form code in edit. Please check it once.

Comment: @David I am getting the string form of True and False in request.POST

Comment: Ahh ok, I never took care on the first line.

Comment: try it like this : `{% if isactive === True %}` and this: `{% elif isactive === False %}`

Comment: Hi, @David === operator could not be used in django template. The data is getting stored in database as expected. The issue is it is not getting updated on User Interface after save.

Comment: So where is your code to update the database?

Comment: Hi @David Please find the code to update database in first code snippet

Comment: Have a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects try the second parameter for forcing update

Comment: @David The record is updating in database, but when next time the get call is executed, still the old data is shown.
e.g. I blocked David, Now David is blocked in the database, but model still shows David as unblocked.
This happens only when deployed to server. On local with same remote database, everything works fine.

This also works on server, if we logout and login again.

Comment: seems you've to instantiate the model new

Comment: In the docu it's said: `Note, however, that like Model.full_clean(), a model’s clean() method is not invoked when you call your model’s save() method.` here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects

Comment: @David So now we have forcefully used `user_profile.full_clean()`, after `save()`. Still no luck.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help, out of ideas :(